# Undefined reference to pow even with -lm and math.h

Tags: c

I am getting an undefined reference to pow error in my main code even with -lm during compiling and include math.h

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define HOUR 60

int main(void) {

        //variables for calculations
        double t, temp;
        int hours, minutes;

        //prints text prompt
        printf("Hours and minutes since power outage? (e.g., 2 30 for 2 hours, 30 minutes) ");
        scanf("%d%d", &hours,&minutes); /*grabs times in hours and minutes */

        t = hours + ((double)minutes/HOUR); /*computes variable t */

        temp = (3*(pow(t,2)))/(t+1)-10; /*computers temp*/

        printf("Estimated current temperature: %.2f degrees Celsius", temp);

}
```

I tried using -lm to fix it when compiling and it still did not work.

`gcc -o -lm exe lab1.c`

Comment: `lm` after source. `gcc -o exe lab1.c -lm`

Comment: You are creating an executable named `-lm` by linking together whatever is already in `exe` (probably a former compile of yours) and the compilation of `lab1.c`. You meant `gcc -o exe -lab1.c -lm`

Comment: Do not edit a question in a way that changes what it asks or to ask a follow-up question. Stack Overflow is intended to be a durable repository of questions and answers, not an interactive help session. The question should be fixed, not changing. To ask a follow-up question, you can post a new question. However, this may not be a good candidate for that. At the very least, you should provide a [mre], including the exact text of the error message.